# SQL conditional aggregation over time

Tags: sql-server, aggregation

For reporting purposes I'm struggling to get some tables in a format which can be easily grouped and aggregated in the report tool (SSRS).

I use SQL Server 2014

I have the following tables:
(dates are shown for the example, but these are actually datetimes)

```
tblEvents

datetimestamp       prio
----------------------------------
2018-05-20          4
2018-08-05          1 
2018-11-12          3
2018-11-13          1
```

Which needs to be 'resampled' to tblCalendar which is a equially spaced time interval table with configurable @start_datetime, @end_date, @number_of_intervals, which I already managed to make with a CTE:

```
tblCalendar

datefrom        dateto      
----------------------------------
1900-01-01      2018-04-12  
2018-04-12      2018-05-31  
2018-05-31      2018-07-19
2018-07-19      2018-09-06   
2018-09-06      2018-10-25
2018-10-25      2018-12-13
2018-12-13      2100-01-01
```

The desired result is:

```
datefrom        dateto      prio
-------------------------------------------
1900-01-01      2018-04-12     -1
2018-04-12      2018-05-31     4     
2018-05-31      2018-07-19     4    
2018-07-19      2018-09-06     1 
2018-09-06      2018-10-25     1    
2018-10-25      2018-12-13     3
2018-12-13      2100-01-01     3
```

For each tblCalendar row, the column prio needs to be add according to:

```
   IF between [datefrom] en [dateto] 1 or more datetimestamp present in tblEvents

        take MAXIMUM of prio's between [datefrom] en [dateto]

    ELSE
        IF before [date1]  1 or more datetimestamp present in tblEvents

            take LAST prio between [datefrom] en [dateto]

        ELSE

            IF after [date2] 1 or more datetimestamp present

                take FIRST prio between [datefrom] en [dateto]

            ELSE

                prio unknown = -1

            END
        END
    END
```

So I would describe the problem as conditional aggregation.

I'm quite new to SQL and tried to fix this with subqueries, conditional joins etc. but cannot get it working. The code below is my current try.

```
SELECT
    datefrom,
    dateto,
    MAX(Case 
            When ((datetimestamp >= datefrom)  AND (datetimestamp <= dateto)) Then prio
            When ((datetimestamp <= datefrom)) Then 'last-known-prio'
            When ((datetimestamp >  dateto)) Then 'first future-prio'                       
            Else    
                -1  -- no prio known ever                                                   
            End),

FROM   tblCalendar CROSS JOIN tblEvents
```

Any help and thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having a look at your tables, I'm not able to identify a common denominator between them. Is there a common denominator?

Comment: Your attempt is missing a GROUP BY, so it's not valid syntax.

Comment: why -1 for range 1900-01-01 ....  2018-04-12. Shouldn't that be 4? And Why 3 for 2018-12-13 ... 2100-01-01. shouldn't that be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't conditional aggregation.

This is a simple select from your `tblCalendar` and then a CASE-based SUBSELECT to get the `prio` value.

psuedocode:

```
SELECT
    datefrom,
    dateto,
    CASE 
        WHEN {between [datefrom] en [dateto] 1 or more datetimestamp present in tblEvents}
          THEN (SELECT {MAXIMUM of prio's between [datefrom] en [dateto]})
        WHEN {before [date1]  1 or more datetimestamp present in tblEvents}
          THEN (SELECT {LAST prio between [datefrom] en [dateto]})
        WHEN {after [date2] 1 or more datetimestamp present}
          THEN (SELECT {FIRST prio between [datefrom] en [dateto]})
        ELSE -1
    END as prio
FROM   tblCalendar
```

And there might be other syntax options with CROSS APPLY etc, but this is the way to think about this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this!